# Не открываются onion сайты в tor браузере

Tags: onion

Пытаюсь перейти на поисковики(Torch, not Evil) через TOR[image: введите сюда описание изображения], и на любые другие onion сайты, получаю это:

Invalid Onionsite Address

The provided onionsite address is invalid. Please check that you entered it correctly.

Details: 0xF6 — The provided .onion address is invalid. This error is returned due to one of the following reasons: the address checksum doesn't match, the ed25519 public key is invalid, or the encoding is invalid.
Почему не грузит сайты, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй открыть любой адрес V3, поддержка адресов V2 прекращена
https://xakep.ru/2021/11/24/tor-v3/

Также, проблема может возникать из-за блокировки TOR в России
https://xakep.ru/2021/12/06/tor-ban/

Comment: Я из Украины, но вот, что на счёт ссылок. Я нашёл сайт с длинными ссылками такого формата: http://xmh57jrknzkhv6y3ls3ubitzfqnkrwxhopf5aygthi7d6rplyvk3noyd.onion. Это и есть v3 ссылки?

Comment: @Дмитрий да, это V3

Comment: На официальном [сайте TorProject] (https://support.torproject.org/ru/onionservices/onionservices-3/) говорится, что проверить подключение можно постучавшись на onion-версию DuckDuckGo - [duckduckgogg42xjoc72x3sjasowoarfbgcmvfimaftt6twagswzczad.onion](https://duckduckgogg42xjoc72x3sjasowoarfbgcmvfimaftt6twagswzczad.onion)